# How to determine the earliest/latest DateTime in a collection?

Tags: c#, datetime

**Question 1:** In a collection of DateTime objects, how to determine which one is the earliest/latest?

**Question 2:** In a collection of objects, how to determine which object has the earliest/latest DateTime property?

For example:

```
class VideoGame
{
    DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which `VideoGame` will be released first/last?

```
var allGames = new List<VideoGame>();
allGames.Add( new VideoGame() { ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 4)} );
allGames.Add( new VideoGame() { ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 14)} );
allGames.Add( new VideoGame() { ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 26)} );
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the OrderBy and OrderByDescending functions of LINQ:

```
VideoGame first= allGames.OrderBy(x => x.ReleaseDate).FirstOrDefault();
VideoGame last = allGames.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

- If allGames has zero items, both first and last will be null.
- If allGames has 1 item, both items will reference that same item

Comment: Word of warning: if allGames contains 0 elements this will throw an Exception.

Comment: Oops, the OP doesn't want the date, but the VideoGame instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use Linq?

```
var min = allGames.Min(s => s.ReleaseDate);
```

Comment: Word of warning: if allGames contains 0 elements this will throw an Exception.

Comment: Good point - didn't think of that.  I'd expect someone to test for that first or put an assertion above it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var videoGame = allGames.OrderBy(x => x.ReleaseDate).FirstOrDefault(); earliest
var videoGame = allGames.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate).FirstOrDefault(); latest
```

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:**

```
DateTime minDate = yourCollectionOfDateTimes.Min();
DateTime maxDate = yourCollectionOfDateTimes.Max();
```

Or, if the collection is large and you don't want to iterate through it twice to get the min and max:

```
DateTime? minDate = null, maxDate = null;
foreach (DateTime dt in yourCollectionOfDateTimes)
{
    if ((minDate == null) || (dt < minDate.Value))
        minDate = dt;

    if ((maxDate == null) || (dt > maxDate.Value))
        maxDate = dt;
}
```

**Question 2:**

```
VideoGame oldest =
    allGames.Aggregate((a, x) => x.ReleaseDate < a.ReleaseDate ? x : a);

VideoGame newest =
    allGames.Aggregate((a, x) => x.ReleaseDate > a.ReleaseDate ? x : a);
```

Or, if the collection is large and you don't want to iterate through it twice to get the oldest and newest:

```
VideoGame oldest = null, newest = null;
foreach (VideoGame vg in allGames)
{
    if ((oldest == null) || (vg.ReleaseDate < oldest.ReleaseDate))
        oldest = vg;

    if ((newest == null) || (vg.ReleaseDate > newest.ReleaseDate))
        newest = vg;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use linq to to get tha latest one.