# How to get the smallest DateTime/Value in List of Lists - using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a *list* of 'events' with each a *list* of `DateTime`s,
like:

```
var events = new List<Event>(){
  new Event("A"){Occured = new List<DateTime>{"1.1.2018", "3.3.2018"}},
  new Event("B"){Occured = new List<DateTime>{"4.4.2018", "5.5.2018"}}};
```

how can I find the one *oldest* `DateTime` in all `events`.

I tried to combine cascaded `OrderByDescending().First()` to find the *oldest* in list of list  ... but no luck

(Please use method syntax for the *LINQ* ;-) Thanx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting earliest date using linq/lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147128/selecting-earliest-date-using-linq-lambda) & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918035/how-to-determine-the-earliest-latest-datetime-in-a-collection.

Comment: what _have_ you tried, which problems have _you_ encountered?

Comment: `DateTime` is saved as string? `<DateTime>` and `"4.4.2018"` won't compile

Comment: Something like `var min = events.SelectMany(c=>c.Occured).Min()`?

Comment: Joining @styx here. This sounds like a clear code request, not a question or a problem. The word "How" in front doesn't make it less imperative..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The recommended "Duplicate question" link is wrong cause it doesn't contain list in list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `SelectMany` in order to *flatten* lists within each event into `IEnumerable<DateTime>`:

```
DateTime oldest = events
  .SelectMany(e => e.Occured) // Now we have IEnumerable<DateTime>
  .Min();
```

If you want an *event* with the oldest (minimum) date you can `Aggregate`:

```
var oldestEvent = events
  .Where(s => s.Ocurred.Any()) // To be on the safe side
  .Aggregate((s, a) => s.Ocurred.Min() < a.Ocurred.Min() ? s : a);
```

Comment: Works! (I forgot about SelectMany()) - and also your second variation will be usefull, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
DateTime smallest_date = events.First().Occured.First();
        foreach (var eve in events)
        {
            eve.Occured.Sort();
            var temp = eve.Occured.First();
            if (temp.CompareTo(smallest_date) < 0)
            {
                smallest_date = temp;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(smallest_date);
```